# I am updating a variable but state is updating in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
var selecteddata = []
var my-data= this.state.list[5];
selecteddata.push({data})
my-data.push(selecteddata)
my-data['year'] = 5;

Addtodatabasefunction(my-data)
```

I am using react native and i getting some data from state to variable so that i can use that data.
but as i am doing my all this.state.list['year'] data is changed with 5. i don't know why this is happening like this.please provide me solution

Comment: can you please provide soem more code?

Comment: @GauravRoy code is updated please check